# Grouping by attributes and counting, postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, grouping, counting

I have written the following code that counts how many instances of each book_id there are in the table soldBooks.

```
    SELECT book_id, sum(counter) AS no_of_books_sold, sum(retail_price) AS generated_revenue
    FROM(
        SELECT  book_id,1 AS counter, retail_price
        FROM shipments 
        LEFT JOIN editions ON (shipments.isbn = editions.isbn)
        LEFT JOIN stock ON (shipments.isbn = stock.isbn)
        ) AS soldBooks
    GROUP BY book_id
```

As you can see, I used a "counter" in order to solve my problem. But I am sure there must be a better, more built in way of achieving the same result! There must be some way to group a table together by a given attribute, and to create a new column displaying the count of EACH attribute. Can somebody share this with me?

Thanks!

Comment: What about just: `book_id, count(*) AS no_of_books_sold, sum(retail_price)` on inner sql without the outer sql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT book_id, 
       COUNT(book_id) AS no_books_sold, 
       SUM(retail_price) AS gen_rev
  FROM shipments 
         JOIN editions ON (shipments.isbn=editions.isbn)
         JOIN stock ON (shipments.isbn=stock.isbn)
 GROUP BY book_id
```

Comment: `SUM(book_id)` will sum all IDs values. Which for sure it is not what the OP wants.